# How to populate a list and send it through jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table of inputs and I want to get all the input values and populate them in a list or array and send them using jquery ajax. Is it possible to do it???

Suppose I have a table of inputs like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="ques1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="ans1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="ques2"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="ans2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="ques3"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="ans3"/></td>
</tr>
```

Now I want those inputs values and populate a list and send through ajax...

```
var arr={};
    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
        arr['ques']=   //Don't know how to get values of ques
        arr['ans']=  //Don't know how to get values of ans
        $(this).push(arr);
    }
    console.log(arr);

$.ajax({
            url: "something.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"arr":arr }, 
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.length!=0){
                   alert("Done!");
                }
        });
```

Comment: Follow any tutorial online for building a form. Most tutorials have you build a contact form but the fundamentals are there. Ex: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59

Comment: `$('ques1').val()` ?  When you searched something like "jQuery get input value" in Google, did you not find *any* examples?

Comment: I'd say it's easiest to use `FormData` object. [See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, push is a method that belongs to the Array object. All arrays can call push.

Secondly, you can get the value of any input in jQuery by selecting it and calling `.val()` This is what your code should look like

```
var arr=[];
    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
        arr.push($('ques' + i).val())
        arr.push($('ans' + i).val())
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for...but only thing you missed the "#" in id selector...It would be $('#ques'+i).val()...thanks...